# Jenkins, Multibranch Pipeline: how to iterate params map

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins. 
I defined multiple check boxes (over 20) for each parameter to be passed to a script, which then starts my application and runs corresponding test case (this might not be an optimal solution but this framework was created before I started at current company and I am not going to refactor it):

```
booleanParam(name: 'cluster_number', defaultValue: false, description: '')
booleanParam(name: 'post_cluster_wu', defaultValue: false, description: '') 
etc.
```

I need to collect user selection for each checkbox (true-false). I would prefer to do it in a loop, like this:

```
sh """

for (element in params) {
// testing:
    echo "${element.key} ${element.value}"
}
"""
```

but keep getting an error:

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: element for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
```

Also tried to put loop outside of shell script. No luck so far.

```
steps {
        echo "username: ${params.OWNER_USERNAME}"

        for (element in params) {
            echo "${element.key} ${element.value}"
        }
...
```

Wonder if anyone was able to loop through params?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try this `params.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }` or change the `element` to some other name. i.e (entry)

Comment: do you get output for `echo "username: ${params.OWNER_USERNAME}"`

Comment: @ Gaurang Shah Yes, getting param values using syntax ${params.OWNER_USERNAME}" works fine. I simply do not like to repeat that code 20 times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'alpha', defaultValue: true)
        booleanParam(name: 'beta', defaultValue: true)
        booleanParam(name: 'gamma', defaultValue: false)
    }
    stages {
        stage('only') {
            steps {
                script {
                    params.keySet().each {
                        echo "The value of the ${it} parameter is: ${params[it]}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```